# <a> tag not appearing as a hyperlink in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]I am trying to populate a hyperlink in a grid through javascript in a dynamic table's cell. The issue is that the link is not appearing. Here is my code snippet:

```
 //Setting EditLink variable properties
                                EditLink = document.createElement('a');
                                EditLink.href = 'https:\\www.google.com';
                                EditLink.name= 'google';

//Creating first cell in the table: 
                                var newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);

// Set first Cell's value
                                newCell1.innerHTML= EditLink;
```

The value rendered:
https://atlas.secure.force.com/www.google.com

Thankks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use appendChild instead innerHTML**

Try to use `appendChild`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the beginning of the table row.</p>

<table>
  <tr id="myRow">
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
    var x = row.insertCell(0);

  var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
   x.appendChild(aTag);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Execute code here
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_insertcell

Comment: Please refer the image to the question for communicating the issue better. The text is appearing but it is not clickable using my code.

Comment: @user4435979 use my first example. that will work for you.

Comment: @user4435979 use `appendChild` instead `innerHTML`

Comment: @user4435979 still facing issue?

Comment: Ratan, thanks! :) It's working now. However, I replaced "www.google.com" instead of "yourlink.htm" and it gave me an error of page not found. Could you please advise. Thanks :)

Comment: @user4435979 you need to add `https://yourlink.htm` .. Just wanted to know what is this `yourlink.htm`?

Comment: @user4435979 or try this `https://www.google.co.in/` and also add `aTag.setAttribute('target',"_blank");`

Comment: Your answer is definitely the best one but I dont see a tick sign by hovering on your answer

Comment: there are no arrows :S